# How do i change my devexpress code to work for only the cell I hover over in tooltip event

Tags: c#, devexpress

The tooltip is working now when hovering over the row of the grid. I need to change it to only do the tooltip when hovering over the 2nd column of the grid.  If I am on the column then I need the value in the cell that I just hovered over. Can't seem to get to work. If I use: `hitInfo.Column.FieldName` that will only work if I don't use the row info. What do I need to add here?

```
private void StrGridToolTipController_GetActiveObjectInfo(object sender, DevExpress.Utils.ToolTipControllerGetActiveObjectInfoEventArgs e)
{
    GridHitInfo hitInfo = gridViewST.CalcHitInfo(e.ControlMousePosition);
    if (hitInfo.HitTest == GridHitTest.RowIndicator)
    {    
        Something lc = gridViewST.GetRow(hitInfo.RowHandle) as Something;   
        //get the cell value to use in rest of the code
        //do the tooltip string of data - that is working
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the VB code we use to when providing tooltips for a specific column....

```
    Dim info As Views.Grid.ViewInfo.GridHitInfo = _gv.CalcHitInfo(e.ControlMousePosition)

            If info.InRowCell Then                      
                If info.Column.FieldName = "KPIStatus" Then
...
```

Comment: As I haven't enough points to comment on nempoBu4's post I'll have to put it here.
 You can't rely on gridViewST.VisibleColumns[1] as this will change if the table columns are dragged/re-ordered. 
Always rely on the column name.

Comment: The grid is UI element and "2nd column of the grid" is always the second visible column. But second column of the underlying datasource can be or can not be the "2nd column of the grid". Moreover there are can be no columns in datasource because you can use the collection of some objects as datasource.

Comment: My bad. I should have put "You can't rely on gridViewST.VisibleColumns[1] as this will change if the _grid_ columns are dragged/re-ordered. Always rely on the column name"

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the value of [`GridHitInfo.InRowCell`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridViewInfoGridHitInfo_InRowCelltopic) property and compare the value of [`GridHitInfo.Column`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridViewInfoGridHitInfo_Columntopic) property to second value in [`ColumnView.VisibleColumns`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_VisibleColumnstopic) collection. To get the value of cell you can use [`GridView.GetRowCellValue`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_GetRowCellValuetopic(9YjA5g)) method with [`GridHitInfo.RowHandle`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridViewInfoGridHitInfo_RowHandletopic) property.
Here is example:

```
private void StrGridToolTipController_GetActiveObjectInfo(object sender, DevExpress.Utils.ToolTipControllerGetActiveObjectInfoEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.SelectedControl == gridViewST.GridControl)
    {
        var info = gridViewST.CalcHitInfo(e.ControlMousePosition);

        if (info.InRowCell && info.Column == gridViewST.VisibleColumns[1])
        {
            object value = gridViewST.GetRowCellValue(info.RowHandle, info.Column);

            //do the tooltip string of data 
        }
    }
}
```